# Why is there no Stream.flatMap(Collection) method?

Tags: java, java-8, overloading, java-stream

Currently, to convert a `List<List<Foo>>` to a `Stream<Foo>`, you have to use the following:

```
Stream<Foo> stream = list.stream().flatMap(fs -> fs.stream());
//or
Stream<Foo> stream = list.stream().flatMap(Collection::stream);
```

I think this is exactly what the method references were designed for, and it does improve readability quite a bit. Now consider this:

```
Stream<Bar> stream = list.stream().flatMap(fs -> fs.getBarList().stream());
```

Having two chained method calls, no method reference is possible, and I've had this happen to me a few times. While it is not a big issue, it seems to drift away from the method-reference brevity.

Having worked with JavaFX 8 a bit, I noticed that a constant of their API's is the convenience methods. Java is a very verbose language, and it seemed to me that simple method overloads were a big selling point for JavaFX.

So my question is, I wonder why there is no convenience method `Stream.flatMap(Collection)` that could be called like:

```
Stream<Bar> stream = list.stream().flatMap(Foo::getBarList);
```

Is this an intentional omission by the folks at Oracle? Or could this cause any confusion?

*Note: I'm aware of the "no-opinion-based-questions policy," and I'm not looking for opinions, I'm just wondering if there is a reason that such a method is not implemented.*

Comment: Whoever downvoted this needs to leave an explanation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Because `Stream` is already a pretty big interface and there's resistance to making it bigger.
- Because there's also the workaround `list.stream().map(Foo::getBarList).flatMap(List::stream)`.

You can also see the original discussion at http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-libs-spec-observers/2013-April/001690.html ; I'm not seeing that option specifically discussed; it may have been discarded already at that point?

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate the answer coming from an expert. I hadn't thought of that workaround, I will definitely use it from now on.